# Using dynamic slots and dynamic components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I create a `MultiStepForm` component currently and want to do this as dynamic as it can be. So I have a `Setup.vue` component, which has a steps array like this:

```
const steps = ref([
    {
        label: 'Company',
        number: 1,
        valid: false,
        skip: false,
        status: 'current',
        component: Company
    },
    {
        label: 'Password',
        number: 2,
        valid: false,
        skip: false,
        status: 'upcoming',
        component: Password
    },
]);
```

Then I have a `MultiStepForm.vue` component which gets the steps as a property and dynamically creates slots like this:

```
let activeStepIndex = ref(1);

<form @submit.prevent="submitStep">
      <template
        v-for="(step, index) in steps"
        :key="step.number"
        :id="'step'+(step.number)"
        v-show="activeStepIndex === step.number"
      >
          <slot :name="'step'+(step.number)" />
      </template>
  </form>
```

In Setup.vue I try to use it like this:

```
<MultiStepForm
            ref="multiStepForm"
            :steps="steps"
      >
          <template
              v-for="(step, index) in steps"
              :key="step.number"
          >
              <component
                      v-slot:[`step${step.number}`]
                      :is="step.component"
                  >
              </component>
          </template>
</MultiStepForm>
```

Now I have the issue that the contents from the `Company.vue` or any other step from the steps array is not visible in the frontend.

When I move the ``` v-slot:[``step${step.number}``] ``` to another template tag like this:

```
<template
  v-for="(step, index) in steps"
  :key="step.number"
>
  <template
      v-slot:[`step${step.number}`]
      >
  <component

          :is="step.component"
          :user="props.user"
          v-model:form="form"
      >
  </component>
  </template>
</template>
```

I get this error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`.

When I place it where the v-for is happening, I do see the contents of all components on the first step.

How can I solve this, that I have 5 slots which are created on basis of the steps array and that the respective contents of the components is placed inside the correct slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MultiStepForm.vue**

[template](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#template) elements do not work with `v-show`. They're not actual elements that will be rendered to the DOM so adding `id` attribute doesn't make sense either. If both of these are needed just use `div` instead to wrap your slot.

```html
<form @submit.prevent="submitStep">
  <div
    v-for="step in steps"
    v-show="activeStepIndex === step.number"
    :id="'step' + step.number"
    :key="step.number"
  >
    <slot :name="'step' + step.number" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**Setup.vue**

When inserting slot content inside of another element it's expected that the *top* elements are your slots, but you nested your slot two levels deep.  Move the `v-slot` to the first element

```html
<MultiStepForm ref="multiStepForm" :steps="steps">
  <template v-for="step in steps" :key="step.number" v-slot:[`step${step.number}`]>
    <component :is="step.component"></component>
  </template>
</MultiStepForm>
```

Comment: Oh my... I had the change in Setup.vue from the beginning, but within the MultiStepForm it was no div. When I change it do being a div, it works. Thank you so much that you have read my comprehensive question!

Comment: And one issue I saw with this approach is, vor example when I am in the last slot which is used, and the component which is used there I target all input elements, vue finds all 16 inputs from the slots before. I assume this is because of v-show, but with v-if it's not working anymore. Whats the solution for this?

Comment: I figured it out, I needed to attach antother div to use v-if and therefore I could remove v-show. It works now.